# Attaching video with video/vnd.google-glass.stream-url after Update XE6

Tags: google-mirror-api, google-glass

Attaching video with the XE6 Google Glass Update is getting stuck.
The code I'm using is this:

```
    String videoUrl = "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9bZkp7q19f0"; 
    if (videoUrl != null) {
      String contentType = "video/vnd.google-glass.stream-url";
      InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream( videoUrl.getBytes( ) );
      MirrorClient.insertTimelineItem(credential, timelineItem, contentType, is);
    }
```

Not sure what I'm doing wrong, but the video is still trying to download and it's killing my battery ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the issue is that you're trying to stream a YouTube page instead of stream the video from that page itself.

Unfortunately, YouTube isn't very forthcoming about how to get the stream for videos that aren't yours. (And not even that helpful about videos that are.)

Comment: This is correct, you need to pass the URL to an actual video file in one of the proper formats (that's hosted on a server supporting streaming).

See http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html for more details on streaming protocols / codecs and container formats supported.

Comment: I have a full working curl command below that shows how to send a timeline card with streaming video (uses NASA video stream).  With regards to the battery killing note, if you add a menuItem with the "DELETE" action to the card, you will be able to delete it on Glass, even if the streaming url is bad.

Answer (score 2):

(Updated with working curl command below)

Based on the documentation here:

https://developers.google.com/glass/timeline#attaching_video

Streaming video to the timeline does not work like attaching a video to the timeline.  Instead you are supposed to make a multipart post.  Note that the content type of the actual post is going to look like this:

```
Content-Type: multipart/related; boundary="mymultipartboundary"
```

Then there will be two more content types, the parts of the multipart content, and the second of those will be the content type you specified.

Some supporting information is here under "multipart upload":

https://developers.google.com/glass/media-upload

If you want a static video that has a cat, you can try this :)

[Sweetie-Cat-Video](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/6562706/sweetie-wobbly-cat-720p.mp4)

Here is a curl command I have tested and works, both with the static video link above, and with a NASA stream as below:

```
curl --header "Authorization: Bearer your_token_here" -H "Content-Type: multipart/related; boundary=mymultipartboundary" --data-binary @input.txt https://www.googleapis.com
/upload/mirror/v1/timeline
```

Where input.txt looks like this:

```
--mymultipartboundary
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8

{ "text": "Sweetie" }
--mymultipartboundary
Content-Type: video/vnd.google-glass.stream-url

http://devimages.apple.com/iphone/samples/bipbop/gear1/prog_index.m3u8
--mymultipartboundary--
```

If I execute this command then go into the timeline, I see a loading card with the [clapper board](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clapperboard) icon, then the first frame of the video with loading text.  Then the stream starts.  I do not see the text that I posted ("Sweetie").  If I return to the card later, in the nasa example, the stream starts from current time.  In the case of the cat video (not a stream), it does not appear that the video is cached, it re-downloads it.

Comment: How about image attachment, i have tried with image/vnd.google-glass.stream-url, it did not work.

Comment: try image/jpeg or similar, if not if you ask a new question someone will answer based on whatever language you are using.  Image attachment does not require multi part and is part of the original java quick start program, you can also see how to attach an animated gif in this fork of that project - https://github.com/mscheel/mirror-quickstart-java

Comment: the url should be https://www.googleapis.com
/upload/mirror/v1/timeline?uploadType=media (there are two other types for the query) check https://developers.google.com/glass/media-upload

Comment: Clocker - the curl command above works with the url specified