# Media Upload Code 400

Tags: python, django, post, google-mirror-api

I am setting up a python web architecture using django. I have successfully inserted a text into my timeline using urllib2 and [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/advanced.html) library. I am now trying to send an image, preferrably a video as well using the requests library.

Here is my body

```
body = {'--':'2bbcee47b4e94819a3a47eeb8967e244',
        'Content-Type' : 'application/json',
        'text':'Hello World',
        '--':'2bbcee47b4e94819a3a47eeb8967e244',
        'Content-Type': 'image/jpeg',
        'Content-Transfer-Encoding':'binray',
        '--':'2bbcee47b4e94819a3a47eeb8967e244'}
header = 'Content-Type': 'multipart/related; boundary=2bbcee47b4e94819a3a47eeb8967e244', 'Authorization': 'Bearer %s' % access_token}
files = {'file': open('555.jpg', 'rb')}
r = requests.post(upload_url,data=body, headers=headers)
```

This returns:

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
   "domain": "global",
   "reason": "badContent",
   "message": "Media type 'multipart/related; boundary=2bbcee47b4e94819a3a47eeb8967e244'         is not supported. Valid media types: [image/*, audio/*, video/*]"
   }
  ],
  "code": 400,
   "message": "Media type 'multipart/related; boundary=2bbcee47b4e94819a3a47eeb8967e244'is not supported. Valid media types: [image/*, audio/*, video/*]"
  }
}
```

I know this is returning bad request; I do not know why. 
Also, the url im POST to is 
    upload_url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/upload/mirror/v1/timeline?uploadType=media'

**NOTE:** I ran a curl command and same result.

Comment: How is this question different than your last one? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17536127/multipart-post-request-google-glass

Comment: It's a different error. I'm only trying to get an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are sending your request to the correct endpoint but with a wrong URL parameter: it should be `uploadType=multipart` instead of `uploadType=media`:

```
POST https://www.googleapis.com/upload/mirror/v1/timeline?uploadType=multipart
```

This is described in our [documentation](https://developers.google.com/glass/media-upload#multipart).